# How to create a "kind class" in Haskell, or ad-hoc polymorphism at the type-level using type families

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-families, data-kinds

I'm studying the type family features of Haskell, and type level computation.
It appears it's quite easy to get parametric polymorphism at the type-level using `PolyKinds`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies, KindSignatures, GADTs, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances, PolyKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

data NatK = Z | S NatK
data IntK = I NatK NatK

infix 6 +
type family (x :: NatK) + (y :: NatK) :: NatK where
    Z     + y = y
    (S x) + y = S (x + y)

-- here's a parametrically polymorphic (==) at the type-level
-- it also deals specifically with the I type of kind IntK
infix 4 ==
type family (a :: k) == (b :: k) :: Bool where
    (I a1 a2) == (I b1 b2) = (a1 + b2) == (a2 + b1)
    a == a = True
    a == b = False
```

I can do things like `:kind! Bool == Bool` or `:kind! Int == Int` or `:kind! Z == Z` and `:kind! (I Z (S Z)) == (I (S Z) (S (S Z)))`.

However I want to make `type +` ad-hoc polymorphic. So that it's constrained to the instances I give it. The 2 instances here, would be types of kind `NatK` and types of kind `IntK`.

I first tried making it parametrically polymorphic:

```
infix 6 :+
type family (x :: k) :+ (y :: k) :: k where
    Z         :+ y = y
    (S x)     :+ y = S (x :+ y)
    (I x1 x2) :+ (I y1 y2) = I (x1 :+ y1) (x2 :+ y2)
```

This works, as I can do `:kind! (I (S Z) Z) :+ (I (S Z) Z)`.

However I can also do `:kind! Bool :+ Bool`. And this doesn't make any sense, but it allows it as a simple type constructor. I want to create a type family that doesn't allow such errant types.

At this point I'm lost. I tried type classes with a `type` parameter. But that didn't work.

```
class NumK (a :: k) (b :: k) where
    type Add a b :: k

instance NumK (Z :: NatK) (b :: NatK) where
    type Add Z b = b

instance NumK (S a :: NatK) (b :: NatK) where
    type Add (S a) b = S (Add a b)

instance NumK (I a1 a2 :: IntK) (I b1 b2 :: IntK) where
    type Add (I a1 a2) (I b1 b2) = I (Add a1 b1) (Add a2 b2)
```

It still allows `:kind! Add Bool Bool`.

Does this have something to do with the `ConstraintKinds` extension, where I need to constrain the `:+` or `Add` to some "kind class"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use open type families for ad-hoc overloading and closed type families for implementation:

```
data NatK = Z | S NatK
data IntK = I NatK NatK

type family Add (x :: k) (y :: k) :: k

type family AddNatK (a :: NatK) (b :: NatK) where
  AddNatK Z b = b
  AddNatK (S a) b = S (AddNatK a b)

type family AddIntK (a :: IntK) (b :: IntK) where
  AddIntK (I a b) (I a' b') = I (AddNatK a a') (AddNatK b b')

type instance Add (a :: NatK) (b :: NatK) = AddNatK a b
type instance Add (a :: IntK) (b :: IntK) = AddIntK a b
```

If we want multiple type-level and term-level methods grouped together, we can write kind classes using using `KProxy` from [`Data.Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html):

```
class NumKind (kproxy :: KProxy k) where
  type Add (a :: k) (b :: k) :: k
  -- possibly other methods on type or term level

instance NumKind ('KProxy :: KProxy NatK) where
  type Add a b = AddNatK a b

instance NumKind ('KProxy :: KProxy IntK) where
  type Add a b = AddIntK a b
```

Of course, associated types are the same as open type families, so we could have also used open type families with a separate class for term-level methods. But I think it's generally cleaner to have all overloaded names in the same class.

From GHC 8.0, `KProxy` becomes unnecessary since kinds and types will be treated the exact same way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

class NumKind (k :: Type) where
  type Add (a :: k) (b :: k) :: k

instance NumKind NatK where
  type Add a b = AddNatK a b

instance NumKind IntK where
  type Add a b = AddIntK a b
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty cool, but could you expand on what exactly makes it work? That is, why does it work? For both your open+closed solution, KProxy solution, and the TypeInType solution.

Comment: Oh but i just tested your first solution, and it still allows `:kind! Add Bool Bool` resulting in `Add Bool Bool :: *`. I was hoping for this to become a type error, instead of being accepted!?

Comment: Also your second solution also allows `Add Bool Bool`. It doesn't show up as a type error.

Comment: That's unavoidable. If we have a well-kinded type family application, and there isn't a matching case for the arguments, we get a stuck application, instead of a pattern error as in runtime. A stuck application cannot be used for anything (with an [esoteric exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.6/docs/Data-Constraint-Forall.html)) so this behavior is safe.

Comment: So, your solution of defining a single poly-kinded closed type family is also safe, it's just not extensible/modular.

Comment: Ok I guess the behaviour is not possible/not desirable?

Comment: It's a valid alternative to the current behavior, perhaps desirable, but definitely not possible currently.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, that's not the only esoteric exception. The same `constraints` package also defines a (nullary) class that can't have any instances using `class Any => Bottom where no :: Dict a`. Since `Any` is a stuck type family (used here at kind `Constraint`!) there is no way to satisfy it, and thus no way whatsoever to write even a bogus instance of `Bottom`. I'm not sure just why that's important, if it is, but it's there.

Answer (score 1):

(This should be a comment but I need more space)

I tried something like

```
class GoodK (Proxy k) => NumK (a :: k) (b :: k) where ...
```

but I failed. I have no idea if what you ask is achievable.

The best approximation I got is making `Add Bool Bool` kind-check, but generate an unsolvable constraint, so that if we ever use it we'll get an error anyway.
Perhaps this could be enough for your purposes (?).

```
class Fail a where

instance Fail a => NumK (a :: *) (b :: *) where
    type Add a b = ()
```